# Tool to rewrite absolute imports to relative

Tags: python, python-import

Is there a tool to automatically rewrite absolute imports in Python to relative ones?

I wanted to provide a plugin to an application and this plugin needs and contains pygments (which uses absolute imports). So I wanted to rewrite the pygments code without doing everything by hand.

The plugin could add an item to sys.path to include pygments but I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: regex replace over files?

Comment: Is there a problem with adding path to `sys.path`?

Comment: Try the combination of os.path.relpath and imp module. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath and http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html. It'll be more useful if you 'll provide some code samples.

Comment: for javascript see [How to convert absolute imports to relative imports with Rollup.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68788133/how-to-convert-absolute-imports-to-relative-imports-with-rollup-js). (most people want the opposite, so this is hard to find)

Answer (score 2):

[chuckmove](http://github.com/sb98052/chuckmove) might work for you. It is a tool that lets you recursively rewrite imports in your entire source tree to refer to a new location of a module.

```
chuckmove --old sound.utils --new media.sound.utils src
```

...this descends into src, and rewrites statements that import sound.utils to import media.sound.utils instead. It supports the whole range of Python import formats. I.e. `from x import y`, `import x.y.z as w` etc.

Comment: last commit 8 years ago...