# How to convert absolute imports to relative imports with Rollup.js?

Tags: typescript, npm, rollupjs

I am doing a code reorganization and am rewriting some of my TypeScript modules that will likely be used by several microservices as packages.

Unfortunately, it seems that using absolute imports enabled by `baseUrl` does not play nicely with this package conversion. For example, I used to `import { Thing } from "Place/That/I/Know";` where `"Place/That/I/Know/"` was really `"src/Place/That/I/Know/"` Now, this results in a `Module not found error`.

I would like to use Rollup.js to convert absolute imports, `"Place/That/I/Know/"`, to relative imports `"./Place/That/I/Know/"`. I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949487/how-to-have-absolute-import-paths-in-a-library-project). But, it seems inconclusive. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make them npm packages. Then install them with npm install and import them by name. Don't waste your time fooling around with paths. If you don't have a private registry and don't want to publish them to the public registry, npm can install from a git url.

Comment: @JaredSmith npm installing from GitHub is exactly how I've been doing it. That's where I've encountered the error.

Comment: Then fix your package.json

Comment: @JaredSmith How? What do I need to set to enable absolute imports when this is a package installed in node_modules?

Comment: https://bytearcher.com/articles/main-property-in-package.json-defines-entry-point/

Answer (score 0):

to rewrite actual "absolute" imports like

```js
import "/some/absolute/path.js"
```

use the eslint rule [path/no-absolute-imports](https://github.com/qdanik/eslint-plugin-path/blob/main/lib/rules/no-absolute-imports.js)

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

NPM=npm
#NPM=pnpm
#NPM=yarn

$NPM init

$NPM install eslint https://github.com/qdanik/eslint-plugin-path

cat >.eslintrc.cjs <<'EOF'
module.exports =
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
  },
  "plugins": ["path"],
  "rules": {
    "path/no-absolute-imports": "error"
  },
}
EOF

cat >jsconfig.json <<'EOF'
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
EOF

cat >test.js <<'EOF'
import "/some/absolute/path.js"
EOF

npx eslint --fix .

cat test.js
```

result

```js
import "./some/absolute/path.js"
```

use case: rewrite absolute import paths of a web app,
to make it work on github pages, where we need relative import paths

limitation: this does not handle paths to service workers

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register("/workers/service.js", {
  type: "module",
  scope: "/app",
});
```